# Keep text moving with Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get an image that fades on scroll – which I've done.

However, as you can [here](http://cargocollective.com/btatest) the text and menu below it is too far away from the picture – the distance grows when I make the browser smaller.

I want to keep the way the text overlays the image on scroll; a similar style to [this.](http://fearthegrizzly.com/)

Aplogoise for the lack of JSFiddle – can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried to change it with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xQQrg/1/) but I lose the text scrolling ove the image (like the FearTheGrizzly ref).

So in short – I'd like to have the text close to the image at the top; and have it move with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your background image changes height when you resize the browser (due to `background-size:100% auto;`, but the element itself doesn't update. You could probably fix this by actually resizing the div by CSS instead of just the background-image, but let's assume you don't want to do that. In this case you'll need to resize the div using JavaScript so that the rest of the content appears in the right place:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $homeDiv = $('.home'); 
    $(window).resize(); //call this onload to make sure the div is initially right
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    ($homeDiv).height($(window).width()/1440 * 600);
    console.log($(window).width()/1440 * 600);
});
```

Of course then your fading might not behave the way you're expecting, so change the `'opacity'` line in your JS too:

```
 'opacity' : 1 - windowScroll / ($(window).width()/1440 * 600 - 30)
```

This does rely on your image having consistent dimensions. There are ways to do it without knowing this, I'm sure, but this is easiest.